# Нужно сделать так чтобы код обрезал текст

Tags: python

У меня код выводит много лишнего текста, нужно сделать так чтобы он выводил первые 11 символов и всё.

```py
a = "Hello my friend!"
print(a)
```

Вывод получается такой `Hello my friend!`
А надо вот такой вывод `Hello my fr`
при этом не меняя саму переменную `a`

Comment: и конечный результат должен записаться в переменную B

Comment: `b=a[:11]`.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Используйте срезы:

`print(a[:8])`